# IIS 8.5 Every single request gets 301 redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I've been migrating from an IIS 7.5 2008 to an **IIS 8.5 2012** server and one of my web applications is having an issue that it's getting my crazy. As you can see in the following screenshot, every single request gets a 301 response to root when is called from application.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI6nD.png)

**To consider**

- Rewrite engine is installed and working. In fact it works fine with all my other webapps.
- I've tried to write a clean web.config with the minimum entries and no rewrite rules, but I get the same issue.
- If I type an image in the URL it works fine. It seems that it's not a handlers issue.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much for your help.

============
Edit:

As Victor recommended, the problem was the Chrome Brower cache. As simple as that.

Comment: Could the culprit maybe be in the application code and not the IIS?

Comment: The same application is working perfectly fine in the 2008 Server, but when I move to the 2012 server I get that issue.

Comment: Can you please clear your browser cache and try again, because in your screenshot all your 301 redirects from browsers cache

Comment: Thank you Victor, clearing Chrome Browser Cache was the solution. My fault was not trying with another Browser.